# Razor pages - Update HTML table after async method has populated a List

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

Trying to run the @foreach loop once items has been populated, I have tried using StateHasChanged() but can't seem to get it to work

Here is my HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field 1</th>
            <th>Field 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.avgHighPrice</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

C# code for populating the items list

```
@code {

    private List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            items = await LoadDataAsync();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }    

    private async Task<List<Item>> LoadDataAsync()
    {
        var database = DBConnection.getDatabase(); 
        IMongoCollection<Item> collection = database.GetCollection<Item>("Prices");
        return await Task.FromResult(items = collection.AsQueryable().ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @D74, what do you mean for `can't seem to get it to work`, do you get any error? Or just cannot display the items? have you check if the items contain value or not?

Comment: Hi @Rena, it seems I was trying to display a too large list so it was eventually timing out.. Oops